# Open a html file from parameter json

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to use the url that comes from that json to call me an html file in window.open () within a d3 function.

could you give me a help

thanks

[image]

```
.style("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", function () {
        var w = window.open(
            'testclick2.html',
            'Resize Window To See Chart Resizing',
            'width=840px,height=680px,resizable=1,' +
            'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0')
    });
```

Comment: Can't you replace 'testclick2.html' with the other URL? Copy and paste it over?

Comment: I need to call the url parameter from the json because there are many urls in each object, and in the window.open I can call that json parameter.

Comment: How do you get the object?

Comment: testclick2.html is an example, but test.json is the file that each object has in this case the object has properties -> url. That is the value that I need to place with some variable to replace testclick2.html and make it dynamic. but I don't know how to access the parameters of the json. that's the problem